# Android JobScheduler - setRequiredNetworkType not working

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I tried to make the JobScheduler with 1 simply constraint condition: **setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)**

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mContext.getPackageName(), JobOneService.class.getName());
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .build();
jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

The JobOneService is extended the JobService class.
I tried to simulate the condition by the way: turn off then turn on the wifi network. But the onStartJob() method not always called  (intermittent called).

Anyone can help me explain why does onStartJob() not always called once I turn on the wifi connection? Thanks

Comment: Please paste JobOneService class code

Comment: Hi @Squti is it matter with JobOneService class? JobOneService will be fired if the condition in JobInfo matched.

Comment: Yes, it's important @kinhkha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, they mentioned that setRequiredNetworkType use for

> Calling this method defines network as a strict requirement for your job. If the network requested is not available your job will never run.

So it checks for network connectivity. If the network is connected then your job will run else your job will not run. If you want that when network connected again your job should run then you have to write your logic for that. It's better to use WorkManager because WorkManager handles it properly.

Comment: Hi @Amit Tiwary, My question is the network is connected (I manually turn off then turn on the wifi connection) but the JobService not getting fired sometime.

Comment: @KinhKha So you are saying that network is already connected i.e you manually turn off then turn on the wifi connection and after that, you scheduled your job but your job is not running?

Comment: Sometimes jobScheduler takes some time before it starts a job. Can you check if your job starts never or it starts after some time?

Comment: Yes maybe you are right. the jobScheduler need some time to stats a job. Maybe I need to use another mechanism to archive my goal.